# Screen capture for multiple-window application

Tags: winapi, wxwidgets, screen-capture

On either Win32 or wxWidgets, is there an easy way to get a screen capture of an application which has several windows open - e.g. floating toolbars and similar - without getting their desktop, etc, as well?

Comment: Nothing built into Win32. You'll have to do the post-processing yourself.

Comment: Didn't imagine there would be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be capturing entire desktop, then enumerating windows and their positions so that you create a region/mask which leaves the windows of the process/application in question. Then applying the mask onto captured image would get you the requested snapshot.